# How to change the color palette of a plot using R and par() command?

Tags: r, github, plot, color-palette, par

I'm using the `glmtools` library for my master thesis, however, the default color palette is not aesthetically pleasing. There is not an argument about the color palette in the `glmtools::plot_temp` help, only says that other arguments are passed to `par()`. I've tried without success to change the palette. Any help?

To install `glmtools`

1. Install `devtools`
2. Load `devtools`
3. Run `devtools::install_github("GLEON/GLMr")`
4. Run `devtools::install_github("USGS-R/glmtools")`
5. Load `library(glmtools)`

The default example is:

```
sim_folder <- run_example_sim(verbose = FALSE)
nc_file <- file.path(sim_folder, 'output.nc')
plot_temp(file = nc_file, fig_path = FALSE)
plot_temp(file = nc_file, fig_path = 'test_figure.png', height = 3, reference = 'surface')
```

And the horrible result is:

[image]

I'd like to use the palette `terrain.colors` or `heat.colors`

Comment: @eipi10 I tried your suggestion `color.palette = heat.colors` inside the `plot_temp()`, however I'm getting the following message: `In par(mai = mai, omi = omi, ps = ps, mgp = mgp, ...) :
  "color.palette" is not a graphical parameter`

Comment: My comments were so long, I decided to add them as an answer instead. Unfortunately, I can't test other options, as I can't get the `plot_temp` example to work. I'll leave my answer up for now, but will delete it if it turns out not to be workable.

Comment: Well, after following through the chain of functions called by `plot_temp`, it looks like `filled.contour` is not called. Rather the external `C` function `.filled.contour` is called directly (`filled.contour` calls the `C` function as well), bypassing `filled.contour`. So it looks like there probably isn't a way to pass the `color.palette` argument. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: One more thing to try: See if `palette=heat.colors` works.

Comment: @eipi10 Unfortunately appears the same message `Warning message:
In par(mai = mai, omi = omi, ps = ps, mgp = mgp, ...) :
  "palette" is not a graphical parameter`

Comment: Ah well, hopefully someone will come along with an option that works. Failing that, you could look at the code for `plot_temp` and the functions it calls and adapt it to write your own function to draw the contour map.

Comment: @eipi10 But thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

With `glmtools`, we had some internal functionality to pass through alternative palettes, but didn't have it exposed in the plot functions yet. Check out the latest version on [github (0.14.8)](https://github.com/USGS-R/glmtools). From `plot_var`, which you can use to plot temperature, you can pass in your own palette function. This should work with any variable you are plotting in heatmap form through `glmtools` package.